# nanoc installation setup in Linux

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nanoc

I'm a newbie to Ruby. Trying to setup [nanoc](http://nanoc.ws) in my machine. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

After the nanoc installation, when I type

```
$nanoc --version
```

I get the following errors:

```
/home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:24:in `default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
from /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:248:in `default_gemfile'
from /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:192:in `root'
from /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `bundle_path'
from /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:400:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
from /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:90:in `configure'
from /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:151:in `definition'
from /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
from /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/nanoc-3.7.0/bin/nanoc:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/bin/nanoc:23:in `load'
from /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/bin/nanoc:23:in `<main>'
from /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/ananth/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Am I missing something from my rvm? Anything to do with $PATH, .bashrc or .bash_profile?
Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in 3.7.0 that will be fixed in 3.7.1.

3.7.0 unintentionally requires a Gemfile to be present when Bundler is installed.

To avoid this bug, either temporarily switch back to 3.6.11, or use a Gemfile (I recommend the latter).